# Autolayout issue with UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, autolayout

I'm trying to add a `UIWebView` to my `UIViewController` programmatically, and i'm getting errors. I have pasted code and error below (code is in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.webView];
NSDictionary *views = @{@"webView": self.webView};
NSArray *horizontal = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[webView]|"
                                                              options:0
                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                views:views];
NSArray *vertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[webView]|"
                                                            options:0
                                                            metrics:nil
                                                              views:views];
NSMutableArray *allConstraints = [NSMutableArray new];
[allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:horizontal];
[allConstraints addObjectsFromArray:vertical];
[self.view addConstraints:allConstraints];

- (UIWebView *)webView {
    if (!_webView) {
        _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
        _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
        _webView.delegate = self;
    }
    return _webView;
}
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.     Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find  the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)

(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dbc5e0 V:|-(0)-[UIWebView:0x14da8010]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14dae350 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dbc640 V:[UIWebView:0x14da8010]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14dae350 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x14dc2880 h=--& v=--& UIWebView:0x14da8010.midY == + 284>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x14e93e60 h=-&- v=-&- UIView:0x14dae350.height == _UIParallaxDimmingView:0x14dbcca0.height>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x14ec1130 h=--& v=--& V:[_UIParallaxDimmingView:0x14dbcca0(504)]>")

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dbc640 V:[UIWebView:0x14da8010]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x14dae350 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I'm trying to get the `UIWebView` to be the width of the device and height of it starting below the navigation bar at the top. Is there anything else i'm missing here? I read the below for this:

http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout-programmatically/

http://derpturkey.com/autosize-uitableviewcell-height-programmatically/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the presence of `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` indicates that you need to set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO for one or more of your views. Try this:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.webView]; // you already have this line.
self.webview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; //add this line.
```

You could also try setting the property in `webView`'s getter method instead of putting it in `viewDidLoad`.

Also, are you calling `[super viewDidLoad]` in your override of `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: This worked for me, but I still don’t understand why. My web view is instantiated from a Storyboard. If I remember correctly, only views instantiated _programmatically_ (i.e,. `init(frame:)`) need setting this property to `false` explicitly (because it is done automatically on instantiation from storyboard/xib). Perhaps it’s an Apple bug that somehow misses UIWebView instances?